# How to use setpci to set link speed?

Tags: windows, drivers, pci-express

I have an 660TI plugged into my notebook via expresscard. I know the expresscard slot is capable of PCIe-2.0 speeds;
[image: screenshow from hwinfo]

When I plug my graphics card in before I have installed the drivers, it shows up as Microsoft Basic Video adapter.

lspci -s 03:00.0 -vvv looks like this:

```
>lspci -s 03:00.0 -vv
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 660 Ti] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 2845
        Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 18
        Region 1: Memory at <unassigned> (64-bit, prefetchable) [disabled]
        Region 3: Memory at <unassigned> (64-bit, prefetchable) [disabled]
        Region 5: I/O ports at <unassigned> [disabled]
        Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
                Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
        Capabilities: [78] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
                DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s unlimited, L1 <64us
                        ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
                DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
                        RlxdOrd+ ExtTag+ PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
                        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
                LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 8GT/s, Width x16, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <4us
                        ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
                LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk-
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
                LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
                DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range AB, TimeoutDis+, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
                DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
                LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 8GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
                         Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
                         Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
                LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
                         EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
        Capabilities: [b4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
00: de 10 83 11 00 00 10 00 a1 00 00 03 00 00 80 00
10: 00 00 00 00 0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0c 00 00 00
20: 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 62 14 45 28
30: 00 00 00 00 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00
40: 62 14 45 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
50: 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 ce d6 23 00 00 00 00 00
60: 01 68 03 00 08 00 00 00 05 78 80 00 00 00 00 00
70: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 b4 02 00 e1 8d 90 05
80: 10 29 00 00 03 3d 45 00 40 01 11 10 00 00 00 00
90: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 13 00 00 00
a0: 00 00 00 00 0e 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
b0: 00 00 00 00 09 00 14 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
c0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
d0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

GPU-Z shows this:

[image]

So both GPU-Z and lspci indicate the graphics card supports PCIe 3.0 (8GT/s).

However when I install the nvidia drivers, lspci looks like this:

```
>lspci -s 03:00.0 -vv
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 660 Ti] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 2845
pcilib: 0000:03:00.0 64-bit device address ignored.
pcilib: 0000:03:00.0 64-bit device address ignored.
        Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 18
        Region 0: Memory at f1000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled]
        Region 1: Memory at <ignored> (64-bit, prefetchable) [disabled]
        Region 3: Memory at <ignored> (64-bit, prefetchable) [disabled]
        Region 5: I/O ports at <unassigned> [disabled]
        Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
                Status: D3 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
                Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
        Capabilities: [78] Express (v1) Endpoint, MSI 00
                DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s unlimited, L1 <64us
                        ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
                DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
                        RlxdOrd+ ExtTag+ PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
                        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
                LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x16, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <4us
                        ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
                LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk-
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
                LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        Capabilities: [b4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
00: de 10 83 11 00 04 10 00 a1 00 00 03 00 00 80 00
10: 00 00 00 f1 0c 00 00 00 0e 00 00 00 0c 00 00 08
20: 0e 00 00 00 81 3f 00 00 00 00 00 00 62 14 45 28
30: 00 00 00 00 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 12 01 00 00
40: 62 14 45 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
50: 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 ce d6 23 00 00 00 00 00
60: 01 68 03 00 0b 00 00 00 05 78 80 00 00 00 00 00
70: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 b4 01 00 e1 8d 90 05
80: 10 29 00 00 01 3d 45 00 00 01 11 10 00 00 00 00
90: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00
a0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
b0: 00 00 00 00 09 00 14 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
c0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
d0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

GPU-Z output now looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, the graphics card now reports that it can only support PCIe 1.1 (2.5GT/s)

My question is, how can I use setpci to set the link speed to PCIe 2.0/ (5GT/s)?
Operating system is Windows 10 Pro

Comment: which eGPU adapter have you used? Maybe it only supports 1.1?

Comment: I'm using a PE4C v3.0 which is supposed to support PCIe 3.0 (8GT/s), however the first screenshot shows my expresscard supports only PCIe 2.0

Comment: Potentially related question (no answer yet): https://superuser.com/questions/1411797/gpu-showing-x1-bus-interface-rather-than-x8